# Random winner from a lotto with $N \sim \mathrm{Pois}(1)$ other people

Tags: probability, expected-value

What is the better answer to this first year probability test question?

> You enter a lottery with $N+1$ people total
>
> $N \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(1)$
>
> A random person is selected to be the winner, what is your probability of winning?

**Answer A:** Your probability of winning is $\frac{1}{N+1}$ which is a RV from $0$ to $1$

**Answer B:** Your probability of winning is about 63%

$$ P(W) = \sum_n P(W \mid N = n) P(N=n) = \sum_n \frac{1}{1+n} \frac{e^{-1}}{n!} = 1 - e^{-1}  \approx .63$$

**My question:** What is the better answer here, A or B? In the real world I would be a little hesitant to say 63% because that loses the fact that if there are many lottos then the probability of winning each one could be different. 63% seems more like an expectation which I suppose the total law of probability is an expectation.

It does make sense to me if someone said "$P(W)$ is the unconditional probability of winning" and $1/(n+1)$ is the probability of winning given $N = n$ but it also makes sense to me if someone said the probability of winning is a RV.

I know this is boring question but can you help clear my confusion. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: The distinction is essentially the difference between the conditional probability (conditioned on $N$) and the [unconditional] probability.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks for your help. Ahhh so if I say the probability of winning is the RV $1/(1+N)$, I am implicitly conditioning on the RV $N$? So given the RV $N$ then the probability of winning is a RV $1/(1+N)$... The conditioning is very clear to me for a statement like $P(W \mid N=n) = 1/(1+n)$

Comment: @angryavian Hmm is this something that makes sense, $P(W \mid N) = 1/(1+N)$? I know you can do things like $E[E[W|N]]$ but didn't think about doing that for a probability $P()$

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Excellent thanks!